Computational Overhead of NodeJs Express Servers
I am working on a multi tenant project that will have a comparatively small set of isolated customer tenants (10-50) which I want to keep isolated to avoid any concerns of incorrectly overlapping compute and data.
The core stack is an Express API server, which then uses Redis and Postgres. My thought was to dockerize this application and host on kubernetes. Then, I can make the application itself single tenant and spin up a different instance of the application for each tenant, so each tenant has its own isolated api server and database.
My concern is the potential steady state overhead of running a nodejs or postgress docker container. If they don't consume many resources while idle, then 50 instances serving N requests each should be comperable to 1 single multi-tenant instance running 50*N requests. But, if there is a significant base overhead to have nodejs running, then I may be better off having a single instance (or a small handful in a cluster) that is shared to better utilize resources.
Research into NodeJs shows that it is relatively common to spin up new processes to do parallel work, since NodeJs is single threaded. In my mind, each single tenant instance is no different then a different process here. So, if spinning up entirely seperate process forks is recommended for normal computation, then the overhead must be minimal. But I am not sure if that applies.

The overhead is mostly going to be memory consumption as each instance of nodejs consumes a fairly significant amount of memory.  You can test yourself how much memory each instance uses.  CPU usage won't really be different.

Running a separate database per tenant also has significant overhead.  I'd be worried about the cost of keeping a bunch of idle resources sitting around, just in case all of the tenants decide to use the application at the same time.  If you had a single replicated multi-tenant application, to some extent tools like the horizontal pod autoscaler can help you scale up under load.
